# Perform the operation or operations when possible.

Tags: matrices

$\begin{bmatrix}-5& -9\\ 9 & 3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}8& 5\\ -4 & -1\end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix} 4& -7\\ -9 & -6 \end{bmatrix}    $

Also, I was trying to add -5+8-4 but I am not show how matrices work.

Comment: When you add matrices, that is how they work. You add them entry by entry.

Comment: For further explanations: [Matrix addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition).

Comment: @HowDoIMath  My answer is \begin{bmatrix}-1& 3\\ 14 & 8 \end{bmatrix}  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\begin{bmatrix}-5& -9\\ 9 & 3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}8& 5\\ -4 & -1\end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix} 4& -7\\ -9 & -6 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} (-5+8-4)& (-9+5+7)\\ (9-4+9) & (3-1+6) \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} -1& 3\\ 14 & 8 \end{bmatrix}.$